# Node JS - how to store Words and access them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

I want to create a system that A)Stores some words in a doc(JSON since i work with Couchbase) and B)and then choose one of those words by a random number generated

Now i have some Questions :

1- How should i store these words ( in a single doc or separately)

2- How should i give each one an index so i can access them? is there a module for this?

3-is there a module for generating random number or i have to do that in pure JS

i did some research for this but i'm open to better ways.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store an array of all words and additionally keep track of each word's index. The following code example might get you on the right track, however, it is not tested and may contain errors:

```
function Dictionary() {
    this.words = [];
    this.indices = {};
}

function add(word) {
    if (this.indices[word] == null) {
        this.words.push(word);
        this.indices[word] = this.words.length - 1;
    }
}

function rand() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.words.length);
    return this.words[index];
}

Object.assign(Dictionary.prototype, { add, rand });


var dict = new Dictionary();
dict.add('cheese');
console.log(dict.rand());
// >> 'cheese'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Words object to handle this for you, as follows:

```
function Words () {

    // Array to store the words.
    var wordList = [];

    // Adds a word to the list, returns its index.
    function addWord (newWord) {
        return wordList.push(newWord) - 1;
    }

    // Adds an array of words to the list, returns the index of the first added.
    function addWords (newWords) {

        wordList = wordList.concat(newWords);
        return wordList.length - newWords.length;

    }

    // Gets the words as a javascript object.
    function asObject () {
        return { words: wordList };
    }

    // Gets the words as a JSON string.
    function asJson () {

        listObject = asObject();
        return JSON.stringify(listObject);

    }

    // Retrieves a random word from the list.
    function randomWord () {

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
        return wordList[randomIndex];

    }

    return {

        addWord: addWord,
        addWords: addWords,
        asObject: asObject,
        asJson: asJson,
        randomWord: randomWord,
        get wordList () {
            return wordList;
        }

    };

}
```

Then you can add words and access them as needed by doing something like this:

```
var words = Words();

// Add words to the list.
var index = words.addWord('apple');
var firstIndex = words.addWords(['orange', 'pear', 'strawberry']);

// Retrieve a random word.
var random = words.randomWord();

// Retrieves the words in object or JSON format.
var wordObject = words.asObject();
var jsonWords = words.asJson();

// Access words by index.
var myWord = words.wordList[firstIndex]; // Returns 'orange'.
```

I'm not 100% clear on what you mean by accessing each one by an index, so I've assumed something like an array index as above. If you meant another sort of index then Calvin's answer provides a different method of indexing by means of an object.